# Undefined index when trying to GET variable

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

In my Flash file I have the following Actionscript code:

```
gameEnd.submitBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, submitScore);
```

The `submitScore` function is as follows:

```
public function submitScore(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.addChild(scoreAdded);
        scoreAdded.x = 165;
        scoreAdded.y = 85;

        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./submitscore.php");
        var thevariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        url.method = "GET";
        thevariables.score = scoreText.text;
        url.data = thevariables;
        navigateToURL(url,"_self");
    }
```

In my `submitscore.php` file I have:

```
<?php

$scorefromflash = $_GET['score'];
echo ("Score: ".$scorefromflash);

?>
```

But this results in the error `Notice: Undefined index: score in submitscore.php`. Anyone know why this isn't working? I've done the name and score in the exact same way but with different variable names and the score never works.

I'd really appreciate any help as I really need to resolve this today.

Comment: Where is the 'score' variable in the submitscore function? If it's not defined then this is why you've got an undefined index.

Comment: Accidentally copied in the wrong line of code to the question. Updated with what it actually is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `score` into `thevariables`

```
var thevariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
thevariables.score = submitScore;
```

And then add thewm to request:

```
url.data = thevariables;
```

Comment: Really baffled as to why it works when I want to output `nameText.text` but not the scoreText